# How can I import text substitutions from Wikipedia "Lists of common misspellings for machines"?

Tags: macos, system-settings, text, text-input

Wikipedia has some nice lists of misspellings for machines:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines
- http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Veelvoorkomende_spelfouten/machines
- http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lista_de_errores_ortogr%C3%A1ficos_comunes/M%C3%A1quinas

How to import them as text replacement definitions in `System Preferences > Language & Text > Text`?

Answer (score 1):

After having read [How can I export text substitutions from Lion for import into Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57960/how-can-i-export-text-substitutions-from-lion-for-import-into-mountain-lion) made clear to me that PlistBuddy was a good way to go.

1. Create a folder for storing related files, for example using `Terminal.app`:

   `$ mkdir ~/Documents/OS\ X`
2. Create a backup of the existing text replacements:

   `$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Print NSUserReplacementItems" ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist > ~/Documents/OS\ X/UserReplacementItems-backup.plist`
3. Create a new document in TextWrangler.
4. Change the encoding of the document (bottom of the window) to *Western (Windows Latin 1)*. Otherwise `Plist Converter.app` replaces any accented characters with an incorrect value.
5. Copy the text from Wikipedia and paste it into the newly created TextWrangler document.
6. [`Replace All`] occurences of '`->`' with '`,`' using the menu command `Search -> Find`.
7. Insert the Prefix '`1,`' on all lines using the menu command `Text -> Prefix/Suffix Lines...`.
8. Prepend the file with this line (as first line): `on,replace,with`
9. Save the file to the  `~/Documents/OS\ X` folder and make sure that the file name ends with '`.csv`'.
10. Drag the '`.csv`' file to [Plist Converter.app](http://code.google.com/p/danilobits/downloads/list) and click the button [`Convert Plist`].
11. Open the newly created '`.plist`' in TextWrangler.
12. Replace all occurrences of '`<string>1</string>`' with '`<integer>1</integer>`'.
13. Save the replace .plist file and quit TextWrangler.
14. Now make sure you *don't have System Preferences open* while doing the import, or it may not work!

    `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Merge '$(ls ~/Documents/OS\ X/common-typos.plist)' NSUserReplacementItems" ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

    Don't forget to replace `common-typos.plist` with the file name you created.

Comment: The English list contains multiple replacements for one source. You need to pick one of the options before step 6 (Find and replace '->' with ',').

Comment: Can you post the final plist file please?

Answer (score 0):

- Close the Language & Text preference pane if it is open
- Copy the list from Wikipedia and run `pbpaste | sed 's|,.*||;s|^|<dict><key>on</key><integer>1</integer><key>replace</key><string>|;s|->|</string><key>with</key><string>|;s|$|</string></dict>|' | pbcopy`
- Run `f=~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist; plutil -convert xml1 $f; open -e $f` and add the entries to the NSUserReplacementItems array
- Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes

Comment: It would be nice to briefly explain what these commands do.