# How can I add autocorrect shortcuts programmatically?

Tags: keyboard, macos

In **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text**, I can add shortcuts that will be available to me globally via autocorrect.

[image: Keyboard section in System Preferences]

Lets say I had 100 of these shortcuts and they were on two Macs, rather than adding/removing each individual item by hand, is there a way to maintain a single `.plist` file that could manage these shortcuts?

Comment: in Lion and Mountain Lion is a hidden file .GlobalPreferences.plist in the local Preferences folder. Does this not exist in Mavericks?

For more information to copy the file under Lion see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57960/how-can-i-export-text-substitutions-from-lion-for-import-into-mountain-lion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy the settings to another Mac by copying `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Note that preferences are cached on 10.9, so if you replace a plist or edit it directly, quitting and reopening applications won't apply the changes. You can apply the changes by running `defaults read -g`, by running `killall cfprefsd`, or by logging out and back in. Changes made with defaults are still applied if you just quit and reopen an application.

Print the current settings:

```
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
```

Add one setting:

```
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems -array-add '{on=1;replace=cmd;with="⌘";}'
```

Replace all settings:

```
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems '(
{on=1;replace=cmd;with="⌘";},
{on=1;replace=opt;with="⌥";}
)'
```

Print the current settings as XML:

```
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems | plutil -convert xml1 - -o -
```

Replace all settings:

```
amp() { local x=${1//&/&amp; }; x=${x//</&lt; }; printf %s "${x//>/&gt; }"; }
out='<array>'
while IFS= read -r l; do
  out+="<dict><key>on</key><integer>1</integer><key>replace</key><string>$(amp "${l%% *}")</string><key>with</key><string>$(amp "${l#* }")</string></dict>"
done <<< 'cmd ⌘
opt ⌥'
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems "$out</array>"
```

Replace `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems` with `NSUserReplacementItems` in 10.8 and earlier.